# Python - Hangman Letter already guessed

Tags: python

My hangman code currently works, and deducts lives for every incorrect guess but if the user has already guessed a letter, and retries that letter, it still deducts a live but should say an error already occured. 
My code is:

```
def playGame(word, lives):
    lst=[]
    dct = start(word, lives)

       1:
            print("Please enter 1 letter")

        elif letter in  lst:
            print("Already in list")

        else:
            count = updatelives(dct, letter)
            print(letter,"occurred", count, "times")
    if guess(dct):
        print(dct["secret"])
        print("Well done, you guessed the word")
    else:
        print("You've run out of guesses.")
        print("The word was", dct["secret"])
    return
```

I tried creating an empty list, append each letter entered adding an elif statement saying "Elif letter in lst: print("Error") but that continues the error even if its not a duplicate. What would be my way around this?

I'm not sure if u need to see any other part of the code but this is the main part

Comment: can you include the `def guess(dictionary)` function? and `updatelives()` for that matter

Comment: appending incorrect letters to an empty list and referencing guesses against that list sounds like a good way to do it, can you show your attempt at that?

Comment: I updated the main post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you append their guess before checking whether it was already in the list:

```
lst.append(letter)
...
elif letter in  lst:
    print("Already in list")
```

So it will always be in the list

Comment: To be clearer... add your `lst.append(letter)` to your else statement, that way it will only be appended to the list AFTER it has gone through all the checks

Comment: This would probably be better if you used a set data structure instead, so that look-ups are O(1).